# Which statistical analysis test can I use when the instances in the sample is not independent?

Tags: statistical-significance, categorical-data, chi-squared-test

I am wondering if the data I have here is eligible to do statistical analysis.

The problem is:
I collected data from 20 person with age less than 20 (Group A), from 21 person with age large than 30 and less than 50 (Group B), from 20 person with age larger than 50 (Group C). 
From group A, B, C, I collected more than 10,000 tweets for each group.

Now I randomly selected 500 tweets from A, 500 tweets from B, 500 tweets from C and annotated whether it is primarily about politics, economy, entertainment and sports.

Now I plan to test the following:
1. Correlation between age and Tweet type
2. Whether there is significant difference in the proportion of tweets between different ages.

SO my questions is:

1. How can I do significance test here? My concern is that the 500 tweets within A, B, C are not independent to each other since they are from 20 users so there are definitely tweets from the same author.
2. If I can, I am planning to use Chi-square. Is that right?
3. If not, what can I do to test the correlations?

Comment: Data is _always_ eligible for statistical analysis. The question is of which analysis to use.

Comment: Is there any recommended method for this problem specifically? Can the generic Chi-square work here?

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "significant difference in the proportion of tweets between different ages"?

Comment: So let's say  we have the data as 300 politics out of 500 tweets in Group B, 10 politics out of 500 tweets from Group A. Can we do a significance test to prove that the A (age<20) has less proportion of political tweets comparing to B (age between 30 to 50)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right to be concerned about the failure of independence: the chi-square test is invalid here -- it will very much tend to reject the null hypothesis even if the null hypothesis is true. Here is a simulation (in R) demonstrating this:

```
N=3  # Number of groups
n=20 # Number of subjects per group
m=25 # Number of tweets per subject
iterations=10;

for(iter in 1:iterations){
  cnt=vector(length=N);
  for(i in 1:N){
    xs=vector(length=n);
    for(j in 1:n){
      xs[j]=rbinom(1,m,runif(1));
    }
    cnt[i]=sum(xs);
  }
  print(chisq.test(cnt)$p.value);
}

[1] 0.009778678
[1] 0.2027057
[1] 0.5131768
[1] 0.0003755583
[1] 0.05393369
[1] 9.91712e-05
[1] 0.1151918
[1] 0.1995197
[1] 0.004757918
[1] 0.6030899
```

Here I've tweaked your assumptions a bit by assuming an equal number of tweets sampled per person and considered the classification of each tweet into only two categories (e.g., political vs. non-political); I used a form of the null hypothesis in which each person has a certain long-run proportion of political tweets, and this proportion is uniformly distributed on [0,1] in all three groups. If the test were valid, then the resulting P-values should follow a uniform distribution on [0,1], since the null hypothesis is satisfied; however, this is far from true, as the test gives very small P-values with moderately high probability.

Anyway, one approach which you could use instead would be this: for each subject, form a vector giving the proportion of their sampled tweets which fall into each of the given categories (so there is one component of the vector for each category); then apply a MANOVA to test for a difference in the means of these vectors between the groups.

Comment: Hi Brent, I got a new question: So in the subjects that were sampled, some of them only have 5  to 10 tweets sampled, while there are subjects with 30 or 50 tweets sampled, should I remove these small subjects as they might introduce more randomness?

Comment: Rather than removing them, probably a better thing to do would be to use a weighted MANOVA, with the subjects weighted by the number of tweets sampled.